# Docker gradlew build fails with HibernateException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am trying to dockerize my spring boot app, which uses gradle and kotlin. I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine as build-and-run
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN ./gradlew build --stacktrace --scan

ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=resource-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=build $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME"]
```

The `./gradlew build` command is working perfectly fine outside of docker, but as soon as I am trying to build the docker image it fails:

```
xyz.resourceserver.ResourceServerApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException
                Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

I do have my database connection properties for spring boot in `application.properties` so I really don't know what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured the application to use an in-memory database when running the tests, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your database connection isn't successful. If your database is running locally, try the following.

Use the --network=host option. This network mode essentially means that the container has direct access to localhost and you can now access localhost:3306. Here's the command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --network=host
```

Comment: I have a problem with the `docker build` command, not the `docker run` command. I don't see how this could help since I can't even build the docker image.